# HTTP status code for maximum registrations

Tags: http, web, http-headers

What would be the most appropriate HTTP response code for if a user has either reached or exceeded the maximum number of registrations on their current IP address?

Answer (score 1):

The HTTP **429 Too Many Requests** response status code indicates the user has sent too many requests in a given amount of time ("rate limiting").

For more information [visit the link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/429)

Comment: I believe you have misunderstood what I am asking. I mean when a user creates enough accounts on my website to exceed the maximum registration limit.

Comment: 207 or 208 http status code be helpful maybe. visit the link : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status

Comment: @BijayeeSaswata neither of those are error codes, and they have a different purpose.